# CAS 6.1.3 SAML issue

Tags: saml-2.0, cas

I'm trying to set up SAML2 authentication in a CAS 6.1.3 installation, but I'm having this error and I can't understand where to intervene to fix it:

`Error: SAML object [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.core.impl.ResponseImpl type does not match interface org.opensaml.saml.saml2.core.AuthnRequest`

Can anyone help me?

Regards

Comment: I'm using this service

`{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.support.saml.services.SamlRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?idpid=C04jzh8f2",
  "name" : "saml",
  "id" : 1,
  "evaluationOrder" : 10,
  "requiredNameIdFormat" : "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent",
  "metadataLocation" : "file:/etc/cas/saml/GoogleIDPMetadata-apps-test.essilor.com.xml",
  "signAssertions": true,
  "signResponses": false
}`